# LINQ .Any to run method

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code below

```
string[] hexSignatureList = {"AA-BB","XX-YY"};

foreach (var hexSignature in hexSignatureList)
{
    if (IsValidMimeType(hexSignature))
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid.");
}
```

How do I convert this above into LINQ `.Any` syntax?

Comment: `hexSignatureList.Any(h => IsValidMimeType(h));` check that return and throw if needed. What have you tried? Also you may have your check backwards.

Comment: He does not have the ! in his code snippet. Though I see it might be accidental

Comment: On another note why linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the fact that it looks like you are throwing on *valid* mimeTypes, maybe a typo? I'll assume you know what you are doing.

The solution should be as simple as just using the `Func<TSource,bool>` *predicate* of [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) then *throwing* on `true`:

> Determines whether any element of a sequence **satisfies a condition**.
>
> **predicate**
>
> `Func<TSource,Boolean>`
>
> A function to test each element for a condition.

**Example**

```
if(hexSignatureList.Any(x => IsValidMimeType(x)))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid.");
```

Or using as a *Method Group*

```
if(hexSignatureList.Any(IsValidMimeType))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid.");
```

Or in the case that your original code is incorrect, and you want to validate against list of valid mime types. You can use [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1)

> Determines whether **all** elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

```
if(!hexSignatureList.All(IsValidMimeType))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid.");
```

<sub>***Note** : Throwing in this sort of way means you loose the context of why it's invalid.*</sub>

Another approach (albeit more verbose) would be to to use `Where`, so can you include the validation failure more explicitly in the exception:

```
var invalidTypes = hexSignatureList
   .Where(x => IsValidMimeType(x)) // .Where(x => !IsValidMimeType(x))
   .ToList();

if(invalidTypes.Any())
    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid types, {string.Join(", ", invalidTypes)}");
```

Comment: What about if I change from `.Any` to `.All`? Will it works the same?

Comment: @Steve yes that seems like where you want to be

Comment: The `.ToList` can be omitted

Comment: @CaiusJard you are likely right, I did however include it to stop multiple enumerations, though in this case there is more than a good chance its not an issue or a concern

Comment: @KlausGütter ahh yeah, thanks for that!